# Quarterly GDP and government spending data sources

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, data-request, government-spending

I am looking for quarterly government spending and GDP data between the years 2019 and 2020 for as many countries as possible. I am posting this question in hopes that someone will point me in the right direction.

I tried creating a custom query from the [OECD National Accounts database](https://stats.oecd.org/viewhtml.aspx?datasetcode=QNA&lang=en) but I am not familiar with its schema, so I found all the options a little overwhelming. Plus, the service is down very often. Perhaps someone here knows an easier way to get these data.

For reference, my ideal dataset would look something along these lines (with more countries and periods of course):

| Country | Series | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | GDP | 2020-Q1 | 150 |
| USA | GDP | 2020-Q2 | 145 |
| USA | Spending | 2020-Q1 | 15 |
| USA | Spending | 2020-Q2 | 20 |